# WKWebView: Google OAuth Popup view

Tags: swift, macos, oauth, popup, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView with an service / website that is using Google OAuth to access Google Drive. Since the normal website opens a popup, closes it and promt a file picker on the services website I need to handle that popup function.

So I have already integrated the following to open the Google OAuth on a separate WKWebView.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        let url = navigationAction.request.url
        if url?.description.lowercased().range(of: "https://accounts.google.com") != nil  {
            self.popupWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
            return self.popupWebView
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

That works as expected – but the empty / white WebView should automatically close – but it doesn't. To get automatically closed I added this Delegate method

```
func webViewDidClose(_ webView: WKWebView) {
    webView.removeFromSuperview()
    print("--- Close webview")
}
```

**Problem 1:** But this method do not get called – maybe because the Google source code closes the popup on a way that get not catched by this delegate method? When I open the exact OAuth URL in real Browser tab it stay open as well – but the popup within the service website gets automatically closed. But this is just about the closing... not the primary problem.

**Problem 2:** But I am really wondering how to send the "postmessage" that comes from the OAuth popup to the main WebView that should display the file picker. How can I catch that postmessage from the popupView and pipe it to the main WebView?

And this is the point I stuck for hours.